# SQL Running Total By Second - TimeStamp / Value

Tags: sql

I'm having troubles writing a query that would aggregate my results per one second. Here I'm creating an example table and make two inserts.

```
create table example (
  start timestamp,
  stop timestamp,
  qty INTEGER
);

insert into example(start, stop, qty)
values ('2019-06-11 09:59:59', '2019-06-11 10:00:04', 14);
insert into example(start, stop, qty)
values ('2019-06-11 10:00:00', '2019-06-11 10:00:03', 12);
```

I need a query that would return me something like this:
[image]

or
[image]

Where 1,2,3,4,5 are seconds from the first 2 inserts. 09:59:59 to 10:00:04 gives 5 seconds.

and 14, 26, 26, 26, 14 is the sum of qty for the rows with the same date. 
14 + 12 = 26 and hence this number. And this addition occurs only for the seconds that occure in the same moment.

Is such a query possible?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the sql dialect doesn't matter to me. I would be happy to see this query in any sql rdbms.

Comment: What result do you want to have if there is another row with `'2019-06-10 09:11:12'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I don't know if I understand your question but in general there will always be two different dates

Comment: If the timeline from the third row would interpolate with one of the timelines from different rows than I would like it's qty column to also be added to the overall sum.

Comment: @Z.Szymon . . . Your conversion of the timestamps to seconds only makes the question harder to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle SQL, you could do something like this:

```
WITH test_data AS (
    SELECT to_date('2019-06-11 09:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS start_time, to_date('2019-06-11 10:00:04', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS end_time, 14 AS qty FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT to_date('2019-06-11 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS start_time, to_date('2019-06-11 10:00:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS end_time, 12 AS qty FROM dual
), seconds_between_first_last AS (
    SELECT MIN(t.start_time) AS first_start_time,
           MAX(t.end_time)   AS last_end_time,
          (MAX(t.end_time) - MIN(t.start_time)) * (24*60*60) AS seconds_elapsed /* Get the number of seconds between the first start time and the last end time */
    FROM test_data t
), second_rows AS (
    SELECT LEVEL AS seconds_since_start,
           d.first_start_time + ((LEVEL - 1) / (24*60*60)) AS target_time
    FROM seconds_between_first_last d
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= d.seconds_elapsed /* Get one row for each second in the interval */
)

SELECT r.seconds_since_start,
       COALESCE(SUM(d.qty), 0) AS total_qty_in_interval
FROM second_rows r
LEFT JOIN test_data d
     ON  d.start_time <= r.target_time
     AND d.end_time   >  r.target_time
GROUP BY r.seconds_since_start
ORDER BY r.seconds_since_start
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to rewrite the subquery with the level clause for postgres?

Comment: @Z.Szymon Sorry, no, I'm not familiar with postgres. If you need answers in a specific DBMS, you could submit a new question and tag it as postgres.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the boundaries easily enough:

```
with ss as (
      select start as ts, qty
      from t
      union all
      select stop, -qty
      from t
     ) 
select ts, sum(qty) as day_qty,
       sum(sum(qty)) over (order by ts) as running_qty
from ss
group by ts;
```

This has all the timestamps when something starts or stops.  It does not "fill in" values.  The best way to do that depends on the database.

Answer (score 1):

In access we have to use a workaround. See the example below.

```
SELECT TimeStamp, (SELECT SUM(Value) AS Total FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.TImeStamp <= T1.TimeStamp) AS Total
FROM Table1 as T1;
```

[image]

[image]